# Invalid Parameter Number Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

So i have the following doctrine query:

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('c','g')
        ->join('c.descendant', 'g');

    $qb2 = $this->createQueryBuilder('c2')
        ->select('c2.id')
        ->addOrderBy('c2.ancestor', 'ASC');

    if ($params['rootGroup']) {
        $qb2->where('c2.ancestor = :groupId')
            ->setParameter('groupId', $params['rootGroup']->getId());
    }

    $in = $qb->expr()->in('g.id', $qb2->getDQL());

    $qb->where($in);
```

when I run the getQuery() i got the following exception message:

> Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

I dump my DQL and i got the following:

```
"SELECT c, g FROM CI\GroupBundle\Entity\GroupClosure c INNER JOIN c.descendant g WHERE g.id IN(SELECT c2.id FROM CI\GroupBundle\Entity\GroupClosure c2 WHERE c2.ancestor = :groupId ORDER BY c2.ancestor ASC)"
```

I also dump the getParameter() of $qb and $qb2 and I got empty array for $qb and an array with 1 Parameter object on $qb2.

I really dont know whats wrong with my query since i expecting that i should bound only 1 value.

Thanks.

Comment: what does `$params['rootGroup']->getId()` return?

Comment: integer. The primary id of the entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`->setParameter('groupId', $params['rootGroup']->getId())` move it to $qb. `getDQL()` returns dql with parameters names, not values.

Comment: It did work. Thanks. Will be accepting this as the answer.